# How to find the position equivalent in an iTextEdit of an EditPoint.AbsoluteCharOffset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

I'm trying delete a class body in using the new Text Editor code model in a Visual Studio 2010 extension. That is, I'm trying to use the Delete method on ITextEdit to delete everything between curly brackets.

I can get access to the Absolute Character Position of the start and end of the class using the

```
codeClass.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody).CreateEditPoint().AbsoluteCharOffset
```

and

```
codeClass.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBody).CreateEditPoint().AbsoluteCharOffset
```

methods on the CodeClass interface. If I then get an ITextEdit from the current IWpfTextViewHost's ITextBuffer, and then try to delete:

```
iTextEdit.Delete(startCharOffset, endCharOffset - startCharOffset);
```

the deletion is incorrect. It appears there isn't a 1:1 mapping between AbsoluteCharOffset on the old model and position in the new text model.

How do I interact between the two models?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AbsoluteCharOffset` returns a value that is actually not the absolute char offset, as it [always counts line break characters as 1 character long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46dwddfh.aspx#remarksToggle), even though "\r\n" is probably what your file uses.  The best way to do the translation is to get the line number and column offset, maybe a helper method like:

```
SnapshotPoint SnapshotPointFromEditPoint(EditPoint editPoint, ITextSnapshot snapshot)
{
    int lineNumber = editPoint.Line - 1;
    int offset = editPoint.LineCharOffset - 1;
    return snapshot.GetLineFromLineNumber(lineNumber).Start + offset;
}
```

(I just learned about this a few months ago, from a performance issue in Dev10 where computing the `AbsoluteCharOffset` is really expensive.  I'd recommend avoiding it every place you can)